# List of Google's projects on Google Code

Tags: open-source, guice, guava

Is there a list of projects from Google itself hosted on Google Code? I have used a few like:

- Guava libraries > https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/
- Guice > https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](https://developers.google.com/open-source/projects) on Google developers, this search should bring them all up:

[https://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label:google](https://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3agoogle)

But it looks like there may be some results which aren't Google affiliated.